# HTML support for 3D

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I just want to know if HTML , JavaScript and CSS can make 3d games and animations or not?

also I heard about [Ajax3d](http://ajax3d.sourceforge.net/), and I want to know if that is true and useful or not

thanks in advance

Comment: whats your highscore here.. http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/wolf/  ?

Comment: Related/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343740/html-code-for-3d-games has a -10 rating but some good answers

Comment: What the... what? wtf does that link have to do with "Ajax"!? It's just a 3D engine! Why do people have to abuse words so badly these days D:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about [WebGL](http://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/) as part of the [canvas](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html) API in Html5?

Also something neat: [CSS 3D transforms](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-3d-transforms/).Probably not suitable for complex games but worth to mention.

Answer (score 0):

Some 3d engine written in js:

Pre3d
three.js
C3DL
CopperLicht 
JS3D
Sandy 3D
O3D 
GLGE
SpiderGL